# Animating two images one after the another

Tags: android, animation, android-imageview

I am animating two layout with images from bottom left corner to above.When I animate these images simultaneously it works fine.But i want to animate them one after another.That means first bottom layout will animate from bottom left to top.Then its above layout will animate from bottom left to top. 
For that i tried below code but it doesn't work as expected.I tried using postDelayed() method to animate second image.But first i see  one layout animating and second layout static then i see both image animating.What should be the proper way of doing this?

```
Handler fbanimation;
   bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.loginbottomup);
ggin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ggin.startAnimation(bottomUp);

fbanimation.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override
public void run() {
afn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
afn.startAnimation(bottomUp);

 }
},1000);
```

loginbottomup.xml

```
    <set 
        android:shareInterpolator="false">
        <translate android:fromXDelta="-300%" android:toXDelta="0%"
            android:fromYDelta="300%" android:toYDelta="0%"
            android:duration="1000"/>
    </set>
```

Comment: do you know `animatorSet`? check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576217/chain-animatorset-android-animation/27576620#27576620)  it is what you need exactly.. so all you have to do is put your animations in a list and use the first option in the answer and android will do the rest

Comment: @Elltz  I want imageview named 'first' to animate first and after its animation is finished then imageview named 'second' to animate..how can I do that?With refrence to John D. answer I have to assign `animation1` to `first` and `animation2` to `second`

Comment: i do not see how the post i linked,and the two answers are not able to solve your requirement. set the animations to the Views and use the animatorSet to play the animations, or the custom way, let a listener on the first animation and when it ends start the second animation, thats the answer provided by Rod. are you beginner Sir?

Comment: @Elltz yeah i am freasher..Suppose i want to animate two imagview.imageview named `first`
"[ to animate first and after its animation is finished then imageview named `second` to animate..can i do tht with AnimatorSet?With reference to Joh's answer how would i assign animation1 to `first` and animation2 to `second`?please help me with code

Comment: have you tried my approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a listener called `AnimationListener` where you attach it in your bottom animation and run the next animation when the animation end which is in the `onAnimationEnd` method.

```
bottomUp.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
       // run the next animation here
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I want imageview named 'first' to animate first and after its animation is finished then imageview named 'second'  to animate..how can I do that?

Comment: @BhuvneshVarma create 2 animationUtils for 2 imageview and then attach the animationlitener just like the above example and within the `onAnimationEnd` create another animationUtils and run it

Comment: I tried ur answer.Now also there seems to be an issue.When I animate two layouts simultaneously it works fine.But if i animate one after another there seems to be some margin problem as the layout seems to cut from the top.I have posted the layout code in question

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the [AnimatorSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html) class:

```
AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
animSet.play(animation1).after(animation2);
animSet.start();
```

The [Android Property Animation documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) should also be of great help here.

Comment: I want imageview named 'first' to animate first and after its animation is finished then imageview named 'second' to animate..how can I do that?I have to assign `animation1` to `first` and `animation2` to `second`

Comment: The AnimatorSet class uses Animator objects (as opposed to Animation objects) which I find to be simpler to work with, as opposed to defining animations in XML. So you could use the ObjectAnimator class to create your animator1 object, then pass them into the play() and after() methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code sample using `AnimationSet` . suppose you have two `ImageView`s the `iv` starts and finishes when its done `iv2` starts.

```
iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); //first image
iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2); // second image
Animation iv1anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom);
Animation iv2anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom);
// the animations are in-built
iv1.setAnimation(iv1anim); // setting the respective anims
iv2.setAnimation(iv2anim);// setting the respective anims
iv1anim.setStartTime(0); // it will start quickly
iv2anim.setStartOffset(iv1anim.getDuration());// its going to delay,for the duration
// of the first image. in millieseconds,so there will be no seconds wait
final AnimationSet anim = new AnimationSet(false);
anim.addAnimation(iv1anim); // the rest is cheese
anim.addAnimation(iv2anim);
anim.startNow();
```

That's what yo want right? hope its helpful. *always upvote, i like upvotes* :)